# How to write something vertically below another equation?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

[image: Figure 1]

I have to write some equations in latex  as shown in Figure 1, but I'm having trouble finishing them.

Answer (score 5):

There are numerous ways of achieving this output. I'd almost recommend using `\underbrace{<stuff>}_{<under>}`, but if you want the look that resembles what you saw, then stack stuff with an `array`, perhaps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\setbelow}[2]{%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    #2 \\ \\ #1
  \end{array}
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setbelow{\dfrac{\overline{u} \, \overline{u}}{b}}{\overline{u} \dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial r}}
  +
  \setbelow{\dfrac{\overline{w} \, \overline{u}}{L}}{\overline{w} \dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial z}}
  =
  - \frac{1}{\rho_0} 
  \setbelow{\dfrac{\smash{\overline{w}^2}\vphantom{\overline{w}}}{b}}{\dfrac{\partial \overline{P}}{\partial r}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever use of arrays! :)

Answer (score 3):

With `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\[\stackMath
    \stackunder[3ex]{\dfrac{\partial\bar{u}}{\partial r}}
                    {\dfrac{\bar{u} \bar{u}}{b}}
+   \stackunder[3ex]{\dfrac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial z}}
                    {\dfrac{\bar{w} \bar{u}}{L}}{\overline{w}}
=
  - \frac{1}{\rho_0}
    \stackunder[2.4ex]{\dfrac{\partial\bar{P}}{\partial r}}
                      {\dfrac{\overline{w}^2}{b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]